# Notation for composition of partial derivative operator with "multiplication by function"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, notation, linear-transformations

Let's say I have an equation $\hat L u = u$, where $u$ is a function $x$ and $\hat L$ is the linear operator defined as
$$
\hat L u(x) = f(x) u(x) + \partial_x (g(x) u(x)) + \partial_x (g(x) (\partial_x u(x)))
$$

How would you write $\hat L$? One could write it as
$$
\hat L = f(x) + \partial_x g(x) + \partial_x (g(x) \partial_x),
$$
and the interpretation of the first and last terms are pretty straight forward,
but the second term could be interpreted as the operator
$$
\hat L u(x) = f(x) u(x) + \partial_x (g(x)) \cdot u(x) + \partial_x (g(x) (\partial_x u(x)))
$$
Is there a better notation? Maybe like this?
$$
\hat L = f(x) + \partial_x \circ g(x) + \partial_x \circ g(x) \circ \partial_x
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use a dot symbol (`\boldsymbol{\cdot}`)
\begin{equation}
\hat{L} = f(x)\mathord{\boldsymbol{\cdot}} +\partial_x(g(x)\boldsymbol{\cdot}) + \partial_x(g(x)\partial_x\boldsymbol{\cdot})
\end{equation}

Comment: That's a good idea! Do you have any source of other people using it for that purpose?

Comment: I don't have a reference on hand but it is a common trick, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286490/what-is-the-meaning-of-expressions-of-the-type-f-cdot-function-dot) for example.